# How to use set methods on obj. reference to change values

Tags: java, setter

```
package restaurantclient;  

public class RestaurantClient { 
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Restaurant r1 = new Restaurant("McDonalds", 1000000, 8.00);
    Restaurant r2 = new Restaurant("KFC", 500000, 6.00);

    System.out.println(r1.toString());
    System.out.println(r2.toString());

    //I would like the code to go here, in-between the toString and the equals comparison. 

    if (r1.equals(r2))  {
        System.out.println("The objects are equal.");
        }
    else {
        System.out.println("The objects are not equal.");
        System.out.println();
        }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("The avg. annual taxes paid by restaurant 1 is: $");
    System.out.println(r1.getAverageTaxes());
    System.out.print("The avg. annual taxes paid by restaurant 2 is: $");
    System.out.println(r2.getAverageTaxes());
    System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Hello. I am new-ish to Java and OOP in general, but passable in Python and C. **I need to find out how to use the appropriate mutator (setter) methods on Restaurant object reference r2, and  change the value of number of people served and the average price per person to the same values in Restaurant object reference r1. I do not want to change the restaurant name.**

Restaurant class:

```
package restaurantclient;

public class Restaurant extends Store {

//Instance Variables
private int peopleServed; 
private double averagePrice; 

//Constructor with 3 parameters
public Restaurant(String storename, int peopleServed, double averagePrice) {
super(storename);
setPeopleServed(peopleServed);
setAveragePrice(averagePrice);
}

//Getters (Accessors)
public int getPeopleServed() { 
return peopleServed; 
} 

public double getAveragePrice() { 
return averagePrice; 
} 

//Setters (Mutators)
public void setPeopleServed(int peopleServed) { 
this.peopleServed = peopleServed; 
}

public void setAveragePrice(double averagePrice) { 
this.averagePrice = averagePrice; 
} 

//toString Method [Must Override]
@Override
public String toString() {
    String information = "Store name: " + (super.getName());
    information += "\n" + "The number of people served: " + peopleServed;
    information += "\n" + "The average price per person: $" + averagePrice;

    return information;
    }

     //Equals Method
public boolean equals (Restaurant restaurant) {

    if (this == restaurant)
        return true;
    if (restaurant == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != restaurant.getClass())
        return false;


    Restaurant other = (Restaurant) restaurant;

    if (super.getName() == null) {
        if (other.getName() != null)
            return false;
    }   else if (super.getName().equals(other.getName()))
            return false;

    if (peopleServed == -1) {
        if (other.peopleServed != -1)
            return false;
    }   else if (peopleServed == (other.peopleServed))
            return false;

    if (averagePrice == -1) {
        if (other.averagePrice != -1)
            return false;
        else if (averagePrice == (other.averagePrice))
            return false;
    }    

    return false; 
}

public double getAverageTaxes() { 
double total; 
total = this.getPeopleServed() * this.getAveragePrice() 
* super.CA_TAX_RATE; 
return total; 
} 
}
```

Comment: Since you don't show what methods Restaurant class has, not sure what you are asking - how to write a setter method?

Comment: What is the definition of Restaurant?  Does it have a set method for those fields, if not you will need to create those methods in the restaurant class.

Comment: Ok, I've uploaded the Restaurant class. Thanks for the help again.

Answer (score 2):

```
r2.setAveragePrice(r1.getAveragePrice());
r2.setPeopleServed(r1.getPeopleServed());
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have defined the setter methods on the class -

```
//Setters (Mutators)
public void setPeopleServed(int peopleServed) { 
this.peopleServed = peopleServed; 
}

public void setAveragePrice(double averagePrice) { 
this.averagePrice = averagePrice; 
}
```

And, as for your question -

> to use the appropriate mutator (setter) methods on Restaurant object reference r2, and change the value of number of people served and the average price per person to the same values in Restaurant object reference r1

First, retrieve the values for the `r1` object using the getter methods, then pass those values in for the setter methods on the `r2` object. As an example -

```
int peopleToSet = r1.getPeopleServed();
r2.setPeopleServed(peopleToSet);
```

or, more concisely -

```
r2.setPeopleServed(r1.getPeopleServed());
```